# Deactivate smoothing

Tags: rendering

So I made a 3d model of a sword, and when I try to render it, the program automatically smooths everything out.
[image: Sword without smoothing]
[image: Sword with smoothing]
Basically, I looked around online, and made sure everything smoothing related discussed there was turned off, and they all were, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program can't really "*automatically smooths everything out*". Without any further info it just looks like you probably have a *Subdivision Surface* modifier on your sword.

Make sure your *View* and *Render* subdivision values are the same, or if you don't want subdivision on your model at all, remove the modifier entirely.